# Deleting NSManagedObject how? Possible by key value match?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I store data using the following method

```
- (NSManagedObject *) createCourseWithCourseCode:(NSString *) courseCode {
     NSManagedObject *course = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Course"   inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [course setValue:courseCode forKey:@"CourseCode"];
    [self saveChanges];
    return course;
}
```

And then I tried to delete with this code, where I am getting the NSManagedObject from a fetch method, but this is not working. 'An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts.'

```
- (void) removeCourseWithCourseCode:(NSManagedObject *) courseCode {
    [context deleteObject:courseCode];
    [self saveChanges];
}
```

I was wondering if I could simply delete the object by finding where the key CourseCode matches a string?

Comment: Are you sure that the context which you are using in [context deleteObject:courseCode] is the same instance of the context in which you are inserting the object?

Comment: Yes, thanks, its the same I checked this before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by passing the object's `objectID` instead of the actual object.

Your code would look like this:

```
- (void) removeCourseWithCourseCode:(NSManagedObjectID *) courseCode {
    [context deleteObject:[context existingObjectWithID:courseCode] error:nil];
    [self saveChanges];
}
```

And you can access an `NSManagedObject`'s ID like this:

```
[someObject objectID];
```

So your first block of code should look something like this:

```
- (NSManagedObjectID *) createCourseWithCourseCode:(NSString *) courseCode {
     NSManagedObject *course = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Course"   inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [course setValue:courseCode forKey:@"CourseCode"];
    [self saveChanges];
    return [course objectID];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get "No visible @interface for NSManagedObjectContext Declares existingObjectWithID "

Comment: [context deleteObject:[context existingObjectWithID:courseCode]];

Comment: Ah sweet, I knew it was something with error: I just didn't know what to put after it haha, i'll try it

Comment: This worked [context deleteObject:[context existingObjectWithID:courseCode error:nil]]; Thanks!